# Meteor two server instances with the same code but different mongo database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, server

I need help to set up two meteor instances in the same computer (this computer is used as a server). Each instance should run the same code (after build the meteor application) and work with a different mongo database.

I have readed and readed to try to found a guide o tutorial to do this but I have not found anything. How I can do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this the hard way and try connect to several mongodb instances via docker containers or just the easy way and associate each of your meteor instance with [a single database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/) inside your mongodb.

I know the naming is confusing because you may think "but mongodb is my database!?". But think this:

mongodb is your database process and for each application you can make mongodb associate a database.

You can do that like this:

**1. open mongo shell of your production db (not your local meteor db)**

```
mongo
```

**2. In mongo shell, create for both of your apps a database [and a database user](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/)**

```
use app1db

app1db.createUser({ 
    user: "app1dbuser",
    pwd: "app1dbpassword",
    roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "app1db" }]
});

use app2db

app2db.createUser({ user: "app2dbuser",
    pwd: "app2dbpassword",
    roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "app2db" }]
});
```

**3. Start your meteor application instances with your databases (assuming local ip and defualt port for your mongodb)**

app1

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://app1dbuser:app1dbpassword@127.0.0.1:27017/app1db"
```

app2

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://app2dbuser:app2dbpassword@127.0.0.1:27017/app2db"
```

The data created by the applications is stored in each db per app. App1 ahas no access to the db for app2 and vice versa.

I hope this helps to achieve whatever your goal is with this.

Comment: Yes. your solution is correct! I created two mongodb databases and each one is assigned to one different Meteor application with MONGO_URL environment variable (before start meteor, I changed MONGO_URL value with the mongo database url desired. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could running the two instances on different ports.
You do something like this:
For the first instance `meteor --port 3000`
Second instance `meteor --port 4000`

They will use the same mongo db.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I can do this but I need each instance use a different mongo database. This is my main problem. A greeting.

Answer (score 0):

In one terminal, start meteor on port 3000, connected to a database called db1

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/db1 
meteor --port 3000
```

In another terminal,  start meteor on port 4000, connected to a database called db2

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/db2 
meteor --port 4000
```